# Sketchup component (window) not cutting through wall

Tags: sketchup

I am trying to add a window to a model of a house, but it is not working how I think it should be. The window is a component that I have made (apparently incorrectly).

The house has walls that are `10"` thick and I would like for the window component to cut through that. I have seen lots of other threads talking about this issue and I have followed the advice given but to no avail.

In my drawing, I have another window that works exactly how I want it to and I am able to toggle the layer visibility on/off and the window will show up (and cut through the wall) and then disappear again (leaving the wall intact).

Here is an image to help explain how I would like it to work. The bay window is the window that does not work. The boxy portion before the glass is the same depth as the wall, and I would like that to be set into the wall.

[image: Google Sketchup example]
**Here is my Sketchup file: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxg8wk470n4Vem5wc0h2SDF6blk/view?usp=sharing)**

*Side Note: Please let me know if I should be posting this elsewhere - I followed the advice of 
[this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203953/what-is-the-appropriate-stack-exchange-site-for-questions-about-sketchup).*

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the component you must enable "Cut Opening". Otherwise your component does not knock out faces at the same place. Also try to add a transparent backing glass.

Still no help? A workaround:

- place the component carefully
- select and copy it to the clipboard
- goto Edit > Intersect faces > With model
- delete your component
- delete the just appeared rectangles from your wall surfaces
- paste in place

*About the layers*: In SketchUP the layers are only display groups. The interactions between the objects does not depend on the layers.

Look at these quides:

[Component basics](https://help.sketchup.com/en/article/3000124)

[SketchUP best practices and applied principles](https://help.sketchup.com/de/article/3000308)

I couldn't open your file because my SketchUP is 2 years old. I can't take the new one because it does not accept my old computer & OS.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up having to delete the portion of the wall (like in your work around idea) were the component intersected and just having a hole in the wall.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but just in case someone else finds this helpful...  I found that my window component was not cutting a hole in the first plane of a wall because I did not leave the original rectangle of the frame.  i.e.  I had built the window by push-pulling the frame up and down.... leaving no line at the intersect point, the cutting plane.  Once I edited the component and added a rectangle around the frame at the intersecting plane... all was good.  This can be solved during the initial build by using the control key with Push-Pull to leave a trace on the inital plane.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but the hole-cutting feature of components is very limited. It only works on thin faces and does not work on groups. You would have to open the group containing the wall and apply the component directly to the face. And even then, it would only cut through the front face.

See https://forums.sketchup.com/t/components-cutting-holes-in-walls/21499 for more details.

As a very quick example, here's a very simple sink on a very simple counter top: [image]

As you can see, it cuts through the top face of the counter (where the sink's cutting plane is) but not through the bottom face. Also, the counter is not a group, or it wouldn't be cut at all.